# CDI Injection and serialization

Tags: logging, cdi, code-injection

I'm considering to use CDI injection for slf4j logger, so I've created a producer.

I'm injecting it into an `ApplicationScoped` bean which is serializable:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public final class CurrentApplicationBean implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    private transient Logger          logger;
}
```

It must be transient because `org.slf4j.Logger` is an interface which doesn't extend `Serializable`, but this means that the logger must be re-injected after deserialization.

**I think that CDI doesn't handle that, what's you knowledge?**

Moreover, the provider always provides a new `Logger` instance beacuse it must set the logger name from the `InjectionPoint`, this means that `RequestScoped` beans have their own logger instance instead of a static per class logger.

**Maybe logging is not a good context for CDI injection... what are your considerations?**

Comment: While org.slf4j.Logger is not marked as serializable for backward compatibility reasons, most if not all actual implementations of org.slf4j.Logger are serializable. Please also see http://glauche.de/2009/08/24/

Comment: >>I think that CDI doesn't handle that, what's you knowledge
No it does not.

>>Maybe logging is not a good context for CDI injection
It's a great context :) Your original code should compile with a warning, you should be just fine

Answer (score 1):

> but this means that the logger must be re-injected after deserialization.

The CDI Container proxy is serializable. When deserialized, the proxy locates/binds to the proper injection. I would not not mark the injection point as transient; as that would prevent the container to locate/rebind the injection and results in a NPE.

> this means that RequestScoped beans have their own logger instance instead of a static per class logger

If your producer method is something like the following

```
@RequestScoped
@Produces   
public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {   
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());   
}
```

The LoggerFactory.getLogger() is creating one logger per class.

> Maybe logging is not a good context for CDI injection... what are your considerations?

It is your choice.

Comment: The CDI-proxy is serializable. But when trying to inject an non-serializable class into a CDI-bean which could become passivated, you'll get an exception at startup: ''cannot produce non-serializable instances for injection into non-transient fields of passivating beans''. So the advice here is to mark the field as transient, which in fact causes problems after passivation/activation.